# Java JDBC > Не возвращается результат для SQL запросов с переменными типа TABLE

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, исключения, jdbc

Выполняю SQL запросы через JDBC. Если запрос содержит переменную типа TABLE, то результат не возвращается:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not
>   return a result set.

Пример SQL запроса:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID int); 
INSERT INTO @Table (ID)
    SELECT RecordID FROM tblData

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Пример Java кода:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Full_Code {


    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String Query = "", s;

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Query.txt"));
        while ((s = in.readLine())!=null) Query += s+"\n"; in.close();
        in.close();

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=MyDB;user=VriL;password=987;");
        stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);

        rs.close(); con.close(); stmt.close();
    }

}
```

Важно отметить:

- Если выполняю тот же запрос руками (через MSSQL Server), то все работает.
- Если запрос не содержит таких переменных, то все работает.
- Экспериментальным путем выяснил, что все ломается на строке "INSERT INTO @Table (ID)".

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести более полный фрагмент кода?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос соответствующим образом.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте SQL оформить так `select @@TABLE as TABLE`
для примера так работает с @VERSION

```
    ResultSet rs_version;
    String msmsql_sql="select @@VERSION as VERSION";
    rs_version=stmt.executeQuery(msmsql_sql);
        while (rs_version.next()){
        out.println("<b>"+rs_version.getString("VERSION")+"</b>");
        }
```

с результатом

**Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) Oct 28 2016 18:17:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 (Build 14393: )**

Comment: Попробовал исправить запрос - теперь даже вручную не гоняется, MSSQL ругается на синтаксис. Не уверен, что я исправил правильно. Не могли бы Вы на примере моего запроса показать, что нужно изменить?

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный вами скрипт является Transact-SQL выражением, соответственно в терминах JDBC он должен интерпретироваться как `CallableStatement`, то есть по сути вы должны скрипт сохранить как хранимую процедуру и вызывать ее через `CallableStatement`

Comment: Попробовал Ваш способ. Процедура выполнилась, но результат получить так и не удалось. Использовал методы:
getResultSet();
getUpdateCount();
getMoreResults();

Comment: Чтобы вернуть `ResutlSet` вам надо использовать `registerOutParameter()` - погуглите

Comment: Использование registerOutParameter() предполагает наличие OUTPUT параметра в хранимой процедуре.
Наткнулся на проблему, что OUTPUT параметры не могут быть типом TABLE (Допустимые типы: AS, CURSOR,
ID, QUOTED_ID, NOTIONAL, DOUBLE). Вариант с созданием своего типа тоже отпадает, так как в этом случае параметр превращается в READONLY. Есть идеи?

Comment: Ваш тип это CURSOR :)

Comment: До того, как нашлось решение, хотел добить этот способ. Следующая проблема - отсутствие такого типа данных в самом JDBC.
(cstmt.registerOutParameter("Parameter", java.sql.Types.???);). По крайней мене изучил OUTPUT параметры, спасибо за Ваш ответ =)

Answer (score 0):

Заменил mssql-jdbc библиотеку на более позднюю версию (6.2.1) - все заработало. Вот такое простое оказалось решение =)